# Trying to access array in JavaScript, result is undefined, no idea why

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to run a very basic script to generate an invoice, right now I'm in the testing phase, trying to work out the kinks of the new InfoPlus system we are using. Anyway, i declare a 2D array named ordersList as a global variable, then add stuff to it, and I can see the results are perfect in the for loop that iterates through the array and logs each value, I get the sum total of the shipped quantities right next to each order number.

Then farther down in the script when I try to access the array again I get a result of "undefined". I have no idea why this is happening, any help would be appreciated.

```
utils.log("Running Invoice Worksheet Script..."); 
utils.log(""); 

utils.log("Viewing Input Entities"); 
var ordersList = [[]];
var incrementerDecrementer = 0;
var firstInputEntity = utils.inputEntities.get(0);
var skuTable = infoplusApi.search("item", "lobId eq '" + firstInputEntity.lobId + "'", null, 100, 'sku');
utils.log("SKU TABLE??? " + skuTable);
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var itemID = skuTable.get(i);
    var finalItemID = itemID.toString();
    var colonPos = finalItemID.lastIndexOf(":");
    finalItemID = finalItemID.slice(colonPos+1);
    utils.log("Final ITEM ID: " + finalItemID);
    var pleaseGiveMeItemInfo = infoplusApi.getTags("item", finalItemID);
    utils.log("item info ?? " + pleaseGiveMeItemInfo);
}
//var SKUinfo = 
for(var i=0; i<utils.inputEntities.size(); i++) 
{
  var inputEntity = utils.inputEntities.get(i); 
  utils.log("       " + inputEntity.orderNo + " SKU: " + inputEntity.sku + " Shipped Qty: " + inputEntity.shippedQty); 
//  utils.log("       " + inputEntity.shippedQty);
  if(inputEntity.orderNo != ordersList[incrementerDecrementer][0])
  {
    var arrayToPush = [inputEntity.orderNo, parseInt(inputEntity.shippedQty)];
    ordersList.push(arrayToPush);
    incrementerDecrementer++;
  }
  else
  {
    ordersList[incrementerDecrementer][1] += parseInt(inputEntity.shippedQty);
  }
}
utils.log(""); 

utils.log("Manipulate data in the original lines..."); 

for(var i = 0; i < ordersList.length; i++)
{
    utils.log(ordersList[i]);
    utils.log("");
}

var orderIncrementer = 0;
for(var i=0; i< utils.inputEntities.size(); i++) 
{
  var line1 = utils.inputEntities.get(i);
  var line2 = null;
  if(i < (utils.inputEntities.size()-1))
  {
    line2 = utils.inputEntities.get(i+1);
  }
  else
  {
    line2 = utils.inputEntities.get(i);
  }
//  utils.log("     Original Line with id: " + line.lobId);
  utils.log("Line1 order num = " + line1.orderNo);
  if(line1.orderNo == line2.orderNo)
  {
    utils.log("Order numbers Match, setting extended charge to zero... ");
    line1.setExtendedCharge(0);

  }
  else
  {
    utils.log("orders list 0 1: " + ordersList[0][1]);
    utils.log("Order numbers don't match, setting extended charge to qty shipped: " + ordersList[orderIncrementer][1]);
    line1.setExtendedCharge(ordersList[orderIncrementer][1]);
    orderIncrementer++;
  }
  //line.description = "Test Change Description"; 
  //utils.setOutputLines(outputLines);
}
```

Log output here: 16432 is the first order number. The problems are the undefined things where I should be getting array values.

Running Invoice Worksheet Script...

Viewing Input Entities
SKU TABLE??? [item:849, item:850, item:234, item:228, item:232, item:236, item:238, item:230, item:226, item:224, item:225, item:223, item:235, item:231, item:233, item:237, item:227, item:229, item:244, item:251, item:240, item:249, item:246, item:253, item:250, item:248, item:243, item:245, item:252, item:239, item:242, item:241, item:247, item:259, item:261, item:257, item:255, item:258, item:260, item:256, item:254, item:265, item:271, item:269, item:273, item:267, item:263, item:262, item:266, item:272, item:268, item:270, item:264, item:278, item:281, item:276, item:280, item:283, item:274, item:279, item:282, item:277, item:284, item:275, item:285]
Final ITEM ID: 849
item info ?? []
Final ITEM ID: 850
item info ?? []
        16432.000 SKU: BBL12P-0045 Shipped Qty: 0
        25140.000 SKU: BBLSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 0
        25140.000 SKU: BBLSP-0038 Shipped Qty: 0
        25140.000 SKU: BBLSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 0
        25140.000 SKU: BBLSP-0040 Shipped Qty: 0
        25140.000 SKU: BBLSP-0041 Shipped Qty: 0
        25146.000 SKU: BBLSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 1
        25146.000 SKU: BBLSP-0038 Shipped Qty: 1
        25146.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 1
        25146.000 SKU: BBPSP-0038 Shipped Qty: 1
        25146.000 SKU: BPC13-0007 Shipped Qty: 1
        25146.000 SKU: BPC13-0008 Shipped Qty: 1
        25146.000 SKU: BPC13-0009 Shipped Qty: 1
        25146.000 SKU: BPC13-0012 Shipped Qty: 1
        25153.000 SKU: BPC13-0007 Shipped Qty: 1
        25153.000 SKU: BPC13-0008 Shipped Qty: 1
        25153.000 SKU: BPC13-0009 Shipped Qty: 1
        25153.000 SKU: BPC13-0010 Shipped Qty: 1
        25153.000 SKU: BPC13-0012 Shipped Qty: 1
        25158.000 SKU: BBPSP-0034 Shipped Qty: 2
        25158.000 SKU: BBPSP-0035 Shipped Qty: 2
        25158.000 SKU: BRZ1-0001 Shipped Qty: 2
        25158.000 SKU: BRZ1-0004 Shipped Qty: 2
        25960.000 SKU: BBPSP-0034 Shipped Qty: 0
        25960.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 1
        25960.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 1
        25961.000 SKU: BBPSP-0034 Shipped Qty: 0
        25961.000 SKU: BBPSP-0035 Shipped Qty: 1
        26144.000 SKU: BBLSP-0040 Shipped Qty: 2
        26144.000 SKU: BBPSP-0034 Shipped Qty: 2
        26144.000 SKU: BBPSP-0035 Shipped Qty: 2
        26144.000 SKU: BPC13-0011 Shipped Qty: 1
        26146.000 SKU: BBPSP-0035 Shipped Qty: 1
        26146.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 1
        27793.000 SKU: BBPSP-0035 Shipped Qty: 0
        27793.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 2
        27793.000 SKU: BPC13-0012 Shipped Qty: 1
        27793.000 SKU: BRZ1-0002 Shipped Qty: 1
        27794.000 SKU: BPC13-0009 Shipped Qty: 4
        27794.000 SKU: BPC13-0011 Shipped Qty: 5
        27797.000 SKU: BBLSP-0040 Shipped Qty: 3
        27797.000 SKU: BBPSP-0035 Shipped Qty: 3
        27797.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 2
        27797.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 3
        27798.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 3
        27798.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 4
        27799.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 1
        27800.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 1
        27800.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 2
        27800.000 SKU: BP9I-0002 Shipped Qty: 2
        27800.000 SKU: BP9I-0004 Shipped Qty: 4
        27801.000 SKU: BBPSP-0035 Shipped Qty: 2
        27801.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 1
        27801.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 1
        27802.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 2
        27802.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 2
        27802.000 SKU: BPC13-0007 Shipped Qty: 2
        27802.000 SKU: BPC13-0009 Shipped Qty: 2
        27802.000 SKU: BPC13-0012 Shipped Qty: 2
        27808.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 1
        27808.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 2
        27808.000 SKU: BPC13-0009 Shipped Qty: 1
        27812.000 SKU: BBLSP-0038 Shipped Qty: 3
        27812.000 SKU: BBPSP-0035 Shipped Qty: 1
        27812.000 SKU: BRZ1-0002 Shipped Qty: 3
        27828.000 SKU: BBPSP-0037 Shipped Qty: 2
        27828.000 SKU: BBPSP-0038 Shipped Qty: 1
        27828.000 SKU: BBPSP-0039 Shipped Qty: 1
        27828.000 SKU: BP9I-0004 Shipped Qty: 4

Manipulate data in the original lines...

16432.000,0

25140.000,0

25146.000,8

25153.000,5

25158.000,8

25960.000,2

25961.000,1

26144.000,7

26146.000,2

27793.000,4

27794.000,9

27797.000,11

27798.000,7

27799.000,1

27800.000,9

27801.000,4

27802.000,10

27808.000,4

27812.000,7

27828.000,8

Line1 order num = 16432.000
orders list 0 1: undefined
Order numbers don't match, setting extended charge to qty shipped: undefined

Comment: At what line do you get undefined?

Comment: There's too much code for me to go ahead and analyse it. As a friendly suggestion, break that code into multiple functions that each do only a simple task. It will be much easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: I get undefined at this line: utils.log("Order numbers don't match, setting extended charge to qty shipped: " + ordersList[orderIncrementer][1]); and the line before that, you can see in the log output where the undefined are.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was when I declared ordersList initially as a 2D array using [[]]. This created one undefined array within my array, and as I pushed new values onto it, that part worked fine, but when I tried to access element 0 it returned undefined. When I tried to access element 1 or higher it worked fine. So I just declared it as a simple array using one set of brackets "[]" and made some edits to other areas of the code and it started working fine.

Hope this helps other people who might run into the same problem.